# Is there a way to spawn 2 new particles when a particle dies?

Tags: particles

I’ve been tasked to come up with an animation that shows a cloud of particles (A) floating around the scene, and then a bunch of new particles (B) enter and flood the scene, binding to the old particles in a 1:1 ratio. Every time a particle B binds to a particle A, particle A changes color.

In 3ds Max I achieved this with a Particle Flow system that spawned 2 new particles upon death, each child being 1/2 the geometry of the parent, with a different material. So it starts out with (A+B), then when an A+B particle dies it spawns a different-colored A and a B. Then I just played the entire animation in reverse.

Is there a way to do this in Blender? I’ve been searching for quite a while. Something to do with Boid particles, perhaps?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with "standard" mechanism. Maybe you can do this with python and Blender API...